# JavaScript – Get object keys in order of declaration, including symbols

Tags: javascript, object, symbols

In JavaScript `Reflect.ownKeys()` is the only function that returns both regular keys and keys that are symbols, as far as I know of at least. Other functions--for example `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`--always return the keys in the order of declaration. However, with `Reflect.ownKeys()` the symbols are always at the end, regardless of that order.

Consider the following example:

```
const symbolProperty = Symbol('symbolProperty');

const object = {

    [symbolProperty]: 'Symbol Property',
    regularProperty: 'Regular Property'

};

console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(object));

// Returns 0: "regularProperty", 1: Symbol("symbolProperty")
```

Is there any way I can get all keys in the predictable order of declaration, like with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`? So for my example:

```
// 0: Symbol("symbolProperty"), 1: "regularProperty"
```

Please note that this should work with any object, without a separate array keeping track of the keys, or a similar "hack." If anyone knows how I can modify the array or of a different function to achieve the expected result it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The behavior of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` is implementation dependent, so depending on the environment it may not produce the results I observed and mentioned in this question.

Comment: This is what ES2015 specifies: positive integer keys in numeric order, string keys in insertion order, then symbol keys in insertion order. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/38218582#38218582

Comment: Use a `Map` if you want everything in insertion order.

Comment: @Barmar What would I use to get the insertion order though?

Comment: Insertion order is the same as declaration order when it's created with an object literal.

Comment: @Dai It always returned the correct order for me when logging regular objects to the console. If it is inaccurate I can update my question to clarify that.

Comment: This [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties) and its accepted answer has a lot more detail.\

Comment: That's implementation-dependent, not part of the language requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the `map` and get keys in the order they were inserted

```js
const symbolProperty = Symbol('symbolProperty');

const map = new Map([
    [symbolProperty, 'Symbol Property'],
    ['regularProperty', 'Regular Property']
]);

for (const key of map.keys()) {
    console.log(key.toString()); //toString() only to show Symbol in console
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this should work for my use case. Thank you so much, will accept when I can!